# Refactorizar código NodeJS - Estructura de Control - Buenas prácticas

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tratando de mejorar mi código y quería escuchar opiniones en base a cómo podría hacer que una **estructura de control** tan simple pueda permitir que, por un lado no ensucie la **legibilidad** como por otro me garantice **flexibilidad**. Estoy aprendiendo las bases y me gustaría saber si el siguiente código puede ser refactorizado o más práctico. No sé si me explico.
Lo que se está haciendo a continuación es filtrar según el parámetro recibido a través de la URL.

```
const min = 0;
const filter = ['higher_price', 'lower_price', 'higher_amargor', 'lower_amargor'];

const GetProducts = async event => {

    if(event.queryStringParameters) {
        const { orderby } = event.queryStringParameters;
        if(orderby === filter[0]) {
            const products = await DB.filterByPrice(-1);
            if(products.length > min)
                return status(200, products);
            return status(404, { status: 'PRODUCTS NOT FOUND' });
        }
        if(orderby === filter[1]) {
            const products = await DB.filterByPrice(1);
            if(products.length > min)
                return status(200, products);
            return status(404, { status: 'PRODUCTS NOT FOUND' });
        }
        if(orderby === filter[2]) {
            const products = await DB.filterByAmargor(-1);
            if(products.length > min)
                return status(200, products);
            return status(404, { status: 'PRODUCTS NOT FOUND' });
        }
        if(orderby === filter[3]) {
            const products = await DB.filterByAmargor(1);
            if(products.length > min)
                return status(200, products);
            return status(404, { status: 'PRODUCTS NOT FOUND' });
        }
        return status(404, { status: 'PRODUCTS NOT FOUND' });
    }

}
```

Alguna recomendación o la estructura en sí está bien por el simple hecho de filtrar bajo 4 posibles condiciones? Teniendo en cuenta que en un futuro alguien desee incorporar más alternativas.

Answer (score 0):

Agrego una alternativa con comentarios en el código:

```
    const min = 0;

    // crear un diccionario que tenga como llave el filtro
    // y como valor la función que se ejecutará. De esa forma
    // si se requieren nuevos filtros solo se agregan al diccionario
    const filters = {
      higher_price: async () => await DB.filterByPrice(-1),
      lower_price: async () => await DB.filterByPrice(1)
    }

    const GetProducts = async event => {

      if (event.queryStringParameters) {
        const { orderby } = event.queryStringParameters;

        // obtener la función asociada con la llave
        let filter = filters[orderby]

        // si la llave no existe lanzar una excepción
        if(!filter) throw 'El filtro no existe'

        // ejecutar la función asociada a la llave
        const products = await filter()
        // condiciones existentes
        if (products.length > min)
        {
          return status(200, products);
        }

       return status(404, { status: 'PRODUCTS NOT FOUND' });

    }
```

Comment: Muy bueno @Lobos voy a implementarlo. Me gustó la implementación de un diccionario.